# Procfile not detected by heroku for a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, procfile

I added a procfile in my root directory with the command:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

but somehow, after committing to my repository and deploying to Heroku, Heroku does not detect it, any reason?

The name of the file: Procfile

The command

```
heroku ps
```

prompts me only the web process

Comment: I know it is kind of a dumb question, but want to cover all bases, you made sure to deploy the change to git and then also push that to Heroku right?

Comment: Yes, that is done.

Comment: Is heroku set up correctly? `$ heroku ps:scale worker=1` I think it is.  "Heroku runs one web dyno for you automatically, but other process types don’t start by default. To launch a worker, you need to scale it up to one dyno:" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile under "scaling a process type"?

Comment: I had an extra line at the end of the Procfile, apparently